# Show welcome banner vsftpd with client lftp

Tags: ftp, lftp, vsftpd

I'm configuring vsftpd with vsftpd.conf and I activate the line 106 that say "ftpd_banner=message".
later I try to connect to this server with a lftp client with anonymous user and don't show the welcome banner.

lftp <IP_server> -u anonymous

If I connect with other client how ftp, I watch a banner, but not with lftp.
It is a error of lftp or I need to configure better this line ? thanks

I'm trying to show a welcome banner with lftp client

Answer (score 0):

Seems like FileZilla doesn't show it anymore too: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=53641

**lftp** doesn't seem to have that feature. Because it may be run by a script, which won't « read » the information. So the information is by definition useless.

Did you try to get a specific information? Like space left? Maybe `du` is what you're looking for?